# How to calculate nth roots without math.h

Tags: c++, math

I have to make a nth root without math.h
This is what I got so far: 
n√(x)=x^(1/n)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main ()
{
float num1,num2,t; t=1;
cout<<"Type your radicand "; cin>>num1;
cout<<"Type your index "; cin>>num2;

for (int i=0;i<1/num2;i++) //this is the exponent
{t=t*num1;}
cout<<"The answer is= "<<t;
system ("PAUSE");
}
```

(Borland C++ 5.5)  Problem is I cant find a way to do x^(1/n)

Comment: `<iostream.h>`?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Wouldn't it be square a number: `x^x?' Then use regular +, -, /

Comment: I´m using "Borland C++ 5.5" ps. i tied going to "math.h" in the include file but I could not find how "math.h" makes sqrt.

Comment: why don't use a `switch`?

Comment: I can´t find a way to use a "switch". I’m going crazy I´ve been trying to do solve it for a whole day and I can´t find a way to solve it :S that´s why I decided to ask here...
Would it help if I translated the Spanish parts of the code?

Comment: You're simply switching "by hand" with `if`s then there's no reason for not able to use switch. And you should create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), dropping all distracting unneccessary code like addition, multiplication... Besides, translate the variable names to English, not quite time consuming for a short piece of code

Comment: And don't use Borland C++, it's decades older than the first C++ standard. It doesn't even have std libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reformulate the question `y = sqrt(x)` as to find the value for `y` such that `y*y - x` equals zero. The easiest way to solve that equation is by doing a bisection on `y` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) between 0 and `x` (because `0 <= sqrt(x) <= x` for all real numbers `x` where `x` should satisfy `x >= 0`).

Alternatively you can resort to Newton's method, although that is slightly more advanced and is not guaranteed to converge (while bisection is, if the correct answer lies within the initial interval).

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is probably using Newton's Method to approximate a square root.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

The equation you want is:
    sqrt(N) = x ~= 1/2 * (N/x + x)

Iterate this a few times until x stops changing fast (start with a guess for x like "1/2 of N"). You can do this by comparing the values of the current iteration (p) and the last iteration (q) like this:

e = (p-q)/p

Once e drops below a value you pick for "close enough" you have arrived at your root your root!

Alternatively, you could

Comment: Ok I tried your equation on paper; x=9, n=2  ---> 0.5*(2/9+9)=6.75 but the sqrt of 9 is 3... I don’t understand the last part; ¿It would be like trying to get the derived part of a root and finding the lowest number? ¿Wouldn’t this take too long?

Comment: That would be N=9, x=1 (or by considering powers of 2, x=2 or x=4 depending on the rounding direction) and then (1+9/1)/2=5, (5+9/5)/2=3.4 etc.